# Why e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync alway be true

Tags: socketasynceventargs

I used SocketAsyncEventArgs to build a tiny Socket Server side. but encountering some problems, when I accepted the client socket, then I tried to use e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync to receive client side info, but I don't know why it always show True to me.
here is the server side:

```
    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process Accept!");
        if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("client online...");
        }

        SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        readEventArgs.AcceptSocket = e.AcceptSocket;
        readEventArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);
        readEventArgs.Completed+=readEventArgsIO_Completed;

        Boolean willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            this.ProcessReceive(readEventArgs);
        }

          this.StartAccept(e);
    }
```

my client side only use the Connect method to connect the server side and send info "Hello Server" to it. but why I am here always got "True"?

```
Boolean willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
```

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved this.
because the buffer size is set too large.
"Hello World" only contains 12 chars.
so I should set the Buffer size as 12.
readEventArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[12], 0, 12);